# upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream ingress-nginx

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using Kubernetes cluster. I have configured my Ingress, to point to my nodejs server. I have not written any nginx file. I see that my request are getting timed out exactly after one minute. When i check logs i see below.

```
*2062249 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
```

Below is my Ingress file.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "120"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "180"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "180"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/send_timeout: "180"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc-mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /abc
        backend:
          serviceName: abc-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Is there a configuration i need to add to prevent this timeout?

Comment: There is a simple way to verify that those timeouts were actually applied - open shell into nginx ingress controller pod and issue command: "cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep proxy_read"

Comment: How do i open shell into ingress pod. I am new to kubernetes

Comment: Give me the output of "kubectl -n ingress-nginx get pod".

Comment: Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden. cannot list pods in the namespace "ingress-nginx": No policy matched.

Comment: Did you install cluster yourself or somebody just gave you access to existing cluster?

Comment: We get cluster from our company.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192225/discussion-between-hacker-and-vasily-angapov).

Comment: Ok then, forget my comment, you don't have permissions to do that.